# Showing a selected value in combobox fetched from database

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Sql = "select status from lk_tb_project_status";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);

    con.Open();

    OleDbDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(DR[0]);
    }
}
```

I am fetching values from database and displaying in combobox(dropdownlist). There are two values in database that is sold and open. What I want is to change selected item on page load. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please explain bit more ..

Comment: actually i am having two values in database that is sold and open as status....and these two values are getting displayed in my combobox ....but i want that on page load the combobox shows sold status as selected value by default....so how to achieve this??

Comment: go through the answer.. combobox will show the "Select Status" when Page_Load()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FindString method to get the index of the first item in the ComboBox with the text "Sold". Then set the SelectedIndex to that:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString("Sold");
```

If it can't find the text "Sold" then the selected index will be -1 and the combo box will display a blank item by default.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set first item as selecteditem.

Try This:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[0];
```

OR

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //it is the index value
```

Comment: no,not this but i i am fetching value from database and want to show one of them as default item...is there any way for that??

Answer (score 0):

```
string Sql = "select status from lk_tb_project_status";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(Sql, con);

con.Open();

comboBox1.Items.Insert(0,"Select Status");
OleDbDataReader DR = com.ExecuteReader();
while (DR.Read())
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(DR[0]); 
}
```